# Can someone tell me best De-Fi learning resources

Tags: solidity, blockchain, defi

I want to learn building some complex smart contracts for borrowing, lending, flash loans etc.
Links to some resources or github repos would help, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here I'll list some:

- The [Ethereum oficial documentation](https://ethereum.org/en/defi/#main-content).
- [Bankless](https://newsletter.banklesshq.com/).
- [How to DeFi](https://landing.coingecko.com/how-to-defi/) book.
- [This article](https://smartvalor.com/en/news/defi-basics) for beginners.

Among many other resources, once you start learning join communities on discord focus on DeFi and your knowledge will grow.